# How to debug this Excel trouble?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Dim MyFile As String
MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)
Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Windows("Jane macro test.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B2").Select
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste



End Sub
```

It keeps saying my code have runtime error 13 and mismatch. Anyone knows how to fix? I am able to use it if I change my MultiSelect to False, but I need it to run on multiple folders. How do I go about doing it?

Comment: Do you know how to `F8` and step through the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro3()

    Dim MyFile      As Variant
    Dim counter     As Long
    Dim wb          As Workbook

    MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

    For counter = LBound(MyFile) To UBound(MyFile)            
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile(counter))
        MsgBox wb.Name

'    Range("A2").Select
'    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'    Selection.Copy
'    ActiveWorkbook.Close
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'
'    Windows("Jane macro test.xlsx").Activate
'    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
'    Range("B2").Select
'    lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'    Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
'    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Next counter


End Sub
```

It iterates through every workbook and then it displays its name in a MsgBox. Thus, you can do something with it in the loop, by accessing the `wb` object.
In general, make sure that you declare `Option Explicit` on the top so your compiler will check that every variable exists and avoid errors at runtime.

Comment: Keep in mind that `MyFile` will hold a string array when you use `MultiSelect:=True`